How to color curves in DensityPlot/ListPlot3D according to external list of two variables?
I have this color function of two variables:
color[a_, b_] := 
 Blend[{White, 
   Blend[{ColorData[3, 6], Black, RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]}, 
    Rescale[b, {-1, 1}]]}, Rescale[a, {0, 1}]]     

I have a data in the form {{x,y,z},{a,b}} and want to use DensityPlot and ListPlot3D  and color according to {a,b} data in the list using the color[a, b] such that  DensityPlot/ListPlot3D reads {x,y,z} and add the color of this point using color[a, b].
A minimal example:
data = Table[{{x, y, Sin[x y]}, {Abs[Sin[x y]], 
     Cos[x y] Sin[x y]}}, {x, 0, 1, 0.05}, {y, -1, 1, 0.05}];


Using VertexColors:
Clear["Global`*"];
data = Table[{{x, y, Sin[x y]}, {Abs[Sin[x y]], 
     Cos[x y] Sin[x y]}}, {x, 0, 1, 0.05}, {y, -1, 1, 0.05}];

color[a_, b_] := 
 Blend[{White, 
   Blend[{ColorData[3, 6], Black, RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]}, 
    Rescale[b, {-1, 1}]]}, Rescale[a, {0, 1}]]

dcolored = (data /. {{x_, y_, z_}, {a_, b_}} :> {{x, y, z}, 
      color[a, b]});

ListPlot3D[Flatten[#, 1] &@dcolored[[All, All, 1]], 
 VertexColors -> Flatten[#, 1] &@dcolored[[All, All, 2]]
 , Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}
 ]



ListDensityPlot[Flatten[#, 1] &@dcolored[[All, All, 1]]
 , VertexColors -> Flatten[#, 1] &@dcolored[[All, All, 2]]
 ]


